# How to display passcode after biometric authentication timeout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, biometrics

How to control the [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) package after timeout?

Comment: do you want to cancel biometric auth process when failed? or receive an error?

Comment: no, I don't want to cancel it I want to display an error, but the popup disappears after 1 minute (fingerprint timeout)!!

Comment: could you attach your code? for better ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, authenticateBioMetrics function to authenticate,if error gets it will return false,
you can watch full code explanation,
https://youtu.be/tw7d3_E5N5M

Can not, set passcode directly via code, you can use BiometricOnly to true, use only biometric authentication.
If it set to false, it will automatically trigger passcode or pattern if enrolled, when biometric failed.

```
 static final LocalAuthentication _localAuthentication = LocalAuthentication();

//check Biometric support
  static Future<bool> canCheckBiometrics() async {
    return await _localAuthentication.canCheckBiometrics;
  }

//check devicelevel auth
  static Future<bool> deviceLevelAuth() async {
    return await _localAuthentication.isDeviceSupported();
  }

//check biometric or devicelevel
  static Future<bool> checkDeviceAuthSupport() async {
    bool isSupport = await canCheckBiometrics() || await deviceLevelAuth();
    return isSupport;
  }

//check wheter fingerprint or face id biometrics enrolled
  static Future<bool> checkEnrolledBiometrics() async {
    List<BiometricType> _enrolledBioMetricsList =
        await _localAuthentication.getAvailableBiometrics();

    print(_enrolledBioMetricsList);

    if (_enrolledBioMetricsList.isEmpty) {
      //
      print("no biometrics enrolled");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  static Future<bool> authenticateBioMetrics() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    bool didAuthenticate;
    try {
      didAuthenticate = await _localAuthentication.authenticate(
          localizedReason: "Please authenticate to continue",
          options: AuthenticationOptions(
              stickyAuth: true,
              useErrorDialogs: true,
              sensitiveTransaction: false));
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == auth_error.notAvailable) {
        print("device does not have hardware support for biometrics");
        didAuthenticate = true; //to handle no hardware auth
      } else {
        didAuthenticate = false;
      }
      //else if (e.code == auth_error.notEnrolled) {
      //   print("user has not enrolled any biometrics on the device");
      // }
      print(e);
    }
    return didAuthenticate;
  }
```

Comment: I'm doing that in my app, the problem is that the authentication popup disappears after timeout then the app is become insecure again!!

Comment: call authenticate function again after timeout, checking whether authenticate success or false